# Connection timed out for netcat after opening port in router

Tags: linux, networking, netcat

So, my situation is that I have one Windows PC and one PC with Kali Linux. On Windows PC I've opened a `netcat` listener on port **4444**. Then on my router I've opened port **4444**.

Finally when I go on kali and, using my mobile data hotspot, I want to connect to my Windows. But when I try it doesn't work, and when I check ports using:

```
nc -vn HOSTNAME PORT
```

it says:

> Connection timed out.

Could anyone help me please? I've already tried using netcat between the two PCs in the same network and it works perfectly, so I thinks it's a network problem. My router is an Asus DSL-N12E_C1.

Comment: Yes, it's a network problem that means the port forwarding rules are incorrect or there's a problem with the router or the way you're trying to establish the connection. You know you'd need to use the public IP when accessing from outside, don't you?

Comment: Which version of `nc` you've got, can you paste it? And the exact output of the error?

Comment: I don't understand your network setup: You have a home network connected with a router to the Internet (cable or ADSL), right?
To this internal network is your Windows PC connected, right?
How did you start the netcat-Listener? `netcat -l -p 4444`?
How is your Kali connected to the Internet?
How did you configure your portforwarding? Did you verify it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

> On Windows PC I've opened a netcat listener on port 4444.

Make sure your `netcat` binds and listens on all IP addresses, not only on localhost, e.g.

```
nc -v -l 0.0.0.0 4444
```

See: [Netcat for Windows](https://joncraton.org/blog/46/netcat-for-windows/).

Then make sure you can connect to that port on the same machine. Then try remotely.

---

> Then on my router I've opened port 4444.

Apart of opening the port, make sure that you've also forwarding that port into the right host like:

- *PUBLIC_ROUTER_IP:4444 <-> INTERNAL_WINDOWS_IP:4444*

---

To connect to the remote port, run:

```
nc -v example.com 80
```

or use `telnet` command, e.g.

```
telnet PUBLICIP PORT
```

---

See also: [Why is "nc -l xxxx" not opening a port?](https://superuser.com/q/455875/87805)